# Linq, entity framework and their usage

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I had to develop system for my university which includes tracking of almost all data (lectures, lecturers, teaching assistants, students, etc..)
My database have like 30 tables, and it's pretty complex.
I used EF and linq to solve connecting to database and querying from it.
But the more I'm going into, the more my queries become to hard to write, and not to mention to maintain.
Here is the example of one query: http://pastebin.com/Za1cYMPa

It is pretty much in chaos as you can see.

So, am I misusing linq (linq can solve this but on different way) or linq just isn't for more complex systems like this one?

This is general question, not one to solve particular problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, **Complexity can be reduced by abstracting your repetitive code into reusable, easily-maintainable components**.

In your particular case, the complexity can be reduced by **implementing the [Repository](http://www.codeinsanity.com/2008/08/repository-pattern.html) and [Specification](http://devlicio.us/blogs/jeff_perrin/archive/2006/12/13/the-specification-pattern.aspx) patterns** to make your code more consistent, easier to read, and easier to maintain.

There is a very helpful sequence of articles by Huy Nhuyen explaining the repository pattern, the specification pattern and how to effectively combine them with the Entity Framework for better code.  These are available at:

- [Entity Framework 4 POCO, Repository and Specification Pattern](http://huyrua.wordpress.com/2010/07/13/entity-framework-4-poco-repository-and-specification-pattern/)
- [Specification Pattern In Entity Framework 4 Revisited](http://huyrua.wordpress.com/2010/08/25/specification-pattern-in-entity-framework-4-revisited/)
- [Entity Framework 4 POCO, Repository and Specification Pattern [Upgraded to CTP5]](http://huyrua.wordpress.com/2010/12/16/entity-framework-4-poco-repository-and-specification-pattern-upgraded-to-ctp5/)
- [Entity Framework 4 POCO, Repository and Specification Pattern [Upgraded to EF 4.1]](http://huyrua.wordpress.com/2011/04/13/entity-framework-4-poco-repository-and-specification-pattern-upgraded-to-ef-4-1/)

Comment: not sure I follow your logic here.  I think the complexity is coming from the database design.  Moving some of these queries into views (or stored procedures) can help simplify the repository layer.  Also, I'm not sure I agree with your assumption that use of Repository and Specification patterns will reduce complexity and improve maintainability.  If anything it moves those concerns to a different layer of the architecture.

Comment: @Jeff, What happens if his boss decides to move the database to Oracle or a Document database?  Then everything has to be recoded, because the business logic has been moved to the SQL database, which is specific to that particular implementation.  You are correct in that it moves the concerns to a different layer, but since the OP discusses LINQ, I have to assume he is a programmer by trade and not a database administrator (Yes, these often overlap but not always).  In this case, it seems like it would be easier to maintain the code than the database.

Comment: that argument is complete b.s. unless you work for a software company.  I've been around too long to know that decisions are not taken that way.  Insulating yourself from something that may or may not happen in the future is just adding complexity.

Comment: @Jeff, I've had to deal with massive migrations like that with poorly designed systems and believe me, it sucks.  Even if the changes are smaller, such as an added field in the table's schema - problems can be caused with the Stored Procedures that are not always easy to debug, unless you happen to be the guy who made the Stored Procedure and you remember.  It's much easier for maintenance to keep all that logic in one place and in one language.

Answer (score 2):

Do you think that query will look better or be better maintainable if written in native SQL? In such case you can hide the query in stored procedure. Once you came into advanced queries it always mess. You can reduce some complexities by hiding subqueries either into database views or into EF query views. But still if you have highly normalized OLTP database and you need to do complex reporting / analysis / data mining query it will always be big and badly maintainable. That is the reason why OLAP systems exist (I didn't check content of your query - just length so don't take it as the reason to build OLAP Cube).

More important is performance of the query ...

Comment: I wanted to ask you about performances in linq general.
How much is linq slower than some native sql?

Comment: @Vajda, The results of some performance tests are posted on [this blog article](http://toomanylayers.blogspot.com/2009/01/entity-framework-and-linq-to-sql.html)

Comment: @smartcaveman Woow, linq to sql isn't much slow in difference to linq to entities.

Answer (score 0):

Ooof, that is pretty nasty.

You should think about your database design.  I believe having so many tables is causing your queries to be overly complicated.  I well placed set of views (or stored procedures) can simplify the querying logic.  However this will not simplify your overall system because at some point you have to connect all these tables.

Comment: -1, Yes, it is ugly.  But there is absolutely no need to use Stored Procedures.  The OP's issue is excessive complexity and maintenance difficulty.  Adding complexity to the least maintainable part of the application is not going to help this in the long run.  There is a better approach.  I don't have a problem with using views.

Comment: @smartcaveman actually this well past the point when you should use stored procedures. Not necessarily to hide complexity but to protect performance. This is already ugly now but have a look at what its generating in SQL profiler then analyse that query

Comment: @smartcaveman Your attack of Stored Procedures is noted.  However your assumption that the SQL layer is the least maintainable is just an opinion, nothing more.  A complex system is a complex system. Nothing you can do can change that without changing the business requirements.